# How to write a script that monitors the creation of .pdf or .PDF files in the current directory?

Tags: linux, shell-script

We need to display only new files created every minute.
I can use watch and find command to either find new files using newermt or find file of certain extension.
But, how to do both together.

Comment: You can use `inotifywait`

Answer (score 0):

A really a quick take on what you can do with `bash` would be:

```
 $ cat myscript.sh

 #!/usr/bin/bash
 while true; do
    timestamp=$(/usr/bin/date) # update of variable timestamp
    sleep 60  #  sleeps during 60s or 1min.
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.PDF" \) -newermt "$timestamp"
 done
```

Run the script `myscript.sh` (after making it executable with `chmod a+x myscript.sh`) inside the directory whose tree you want to search.

You will need to kill that script manually with CTRL+C if you want to stop it and while it runs in the foreground. If you want something more elaborate, you can always ask another question or search the internet.

Note that as a function of how deep in your directory tree you go, your `find` command may need time to actually parse the tree and so in the end, with this naive solution, you may actually parse tree files every 60s and a bit more, "a bit more" being the time it takes for parsing / stat'ing files.  There are ways to correct for that if it is important to you.

Comment: I used newermt but for some reason it it also listing files before the timestamp.

Comment: I figured this out yesterday, and it works as well                                                                 watch -n 60 find . -type f -cmin -1 -iname "\*.pdf"

Comment: @user16566918, well done. Just thought you wanted to use `-newermt`.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use `inotifywait` to monitor a specific directory, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r path action file
  do 
    [[ $file == @(*.pdf|*.PDF) ]] && printf '%s %s\n' "File $file was ${action,,}d in $path"
  done < <(inotifywait -r -m testdir/ -e create,delete,moved_to)
```

The results should look like:
[image]